# How does javascript es6 iterator lazy evaluation work in memory?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator, generator

javascipt es6 iterator lazy evaluation memory operation process

When it comes to the JavaScript ES6 iterator object and next () call, it is said to operate in a delayed evaluation form.

If an iterator object is returned as a generator function, the function does not execute immediately. The next () function of the returned iterator object must be executed to execute it.
At this time, if the execution code evaluation formula goes up on the call stack and meets yield, will it disappear from the call stack?

```
function* loop(num) {

    while(true) {
    yield num + 1;
  }

}

loopIterator = loop(1); // return iterator obj
console.log(loopIterator.next()); // call
console.log(loopIterator.next()); // call
```

Comment: It would help tremendously if you could post an example.

Comment: None of "*iterator lazy memory operation*" seem to be relevant to your question? Please put a question in the title of the post, not a tag soup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you mean by "goes up on the call stack".

The call to `next()` places the code in the generator function on the call stack and jumps to the place where it left off. This will execute normally, evaluating function calls inside the generator function using the call stack normally. At some point, the execution meets a `yield` keyword, which is necessarily in the stack frame of the generator function code. It then stores the state, removes the generator function code from the call stack, and returns from the `next()`  call.

Comment: call stack is Execution Context

Comment: Yes, it's a stack of execution context, but no, it does not "go up on the call stack" before it meets `yield`. It already is in that very execution context that it entered with the `.next()`  call.

Comment: [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)

Is this the order?

1.Execute generator function

2. Generator object return (iterator)

3. Run iterator.next ()

4. Generator function execution context creation (in stack)

5. Exit when you meet yeild

6. Delete generator function execution context (out stack)

Comment: I still don't know how iterators are lazy-evaluation and beneficial to memory

Comment: @zero86 Yes, that's the order.

Comment: @zero86 iterators (and generators) are not "lazy-evaluation" and "beneficial to memory" in and of themselves. However, when you have two solutions for a problem, e.g. using an iterator vs using an array, *then* you can compare them by memory usage.

Comment: [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)

We confirmed that the concept of lazy evaluation is delayed until a result is needed.

Does this mean that calling the next () function adds the generator function execution context to the execution context and pushes the value to memory?

If so, does the generator object simply store the execution context state when it encounters yield?

Comment: "*Does this mean that calling the `next()` function adds the generator function execution context to the call stack? Does the generator object simply store the execution context state when it encounters yield?*" - yes, yes. That's what my answer meant to say.